# Learning over non-independent joint distributions

Tags: distributions, optimization, joint-distribution, constrained-optimization

For integer $n\geq 1$, I have a "goodness" function $f_n(F)$ that takes as input a given joint CDF $F$ of $n$ variables, and spits out a number in $[0,1]$ on how "good" $F$ is. The larger the better. You can assume the $n$ variables have support on $[0,1]$.

I would like to maximize $f_n(F)$ subject to $F$ being a joint CDF of $n$ distributions. I am trying to represent $F$ in an appropriate hypothesis space that I can optimize over.

For $f_1(F)$, I assumed $F(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{20} a_i x^i$ (i.e is a polynomial) subject to $\sum_{i=1}^{20} a_i=1$ and $a_i\geq 0$. This is clearly a relaxation since not every CDF can be written in that form, but $F$ represents a valid CDF. I then optimized $f_1$ over $\{a_i\}$ and found a "good enough" CDF $F$.

For $f_2(F)$, I first assumed $F=F_1F_2$ and optimized again over $F_1, F_2$ in the same way for $n=1$. However, since this is assuming independence, the goodness of $f_2$ was very bad.

Is there a more general hypothesis space to consider for $F(x,y)$ that incorporates the possibility for some dependence but also is easy to enforce the CDF constraints on?

Comment: @jbowman The support of the variables is $[0,1]$ so $F(1)=1$ (i.e your example is the uniform distribution).

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for  copulas. They are essentially standardized multivariate distributions and there are examples of parametrized families

Comment: @picky_porpoise Thanks, that looks exactly like what I am interested in.